# R order list based on multiple characters from each item

Tags: r

I'd like to sort a list based on more than the first character of each item in that list. The list contains chr data though some of those characters are digits. I've been trying to use a combination of `substr()` and `order` but to no avail.

For example:

```r
mylist <- c('0_times','3-10_times','11_20_times','1-2_times','more_than_20_times')
mylist[order(substr(mylist,1,2))]
```

However, this results in `11-20_times` being placed prior to `3-10_times`:

```
[1] "0_times"            "1-2_times"          "11-20_times"        "3-10_times"         "more_than_20_times"
```

**Update**
To provide further detail on the use case.
My data is similar to the following:

```r
mydf <- data.frame(X1=c("0_times","3-10_times", "11-20_times", "1-2_times","3-10_times",
                        "0_times","3-10_times", "11-20_times", "1-2_times","3-10_times" ),
                   X2=c('a','b','c','d','e','a','b','c','d','e'))

mydf2 <- data.frame(names = colnames(mydf))

mydf2$vals <- lapply(mydf, unique)
```

It is the vectors in `mydf2$vals` that I would like to sort. While the solution from @AllanCameron functions perfectly on a single vector, I'd like to apply that to each vector contained within `mydf2$vals` but cannot figure out how.

I have attempted to use unlist to access the lists contained but again can only do this on an individual row basis:

```r
unlist(mydf2[1,'vals'], use.names=FALSE)
```

My inexperience evident here but I've been struggling with this all day.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This requires a bit of string parsing and converting to numeric:

```r
o <- sapply(strsplit(mylist, '\\D+'), function(x) min(as.numeric(x[nzchar(x)])))
mylist[order(o)]
#> [1] "0_times"            "1-2_times"          "3-10_times"        
#> [4] "11_20_times"        "more_than_20_times"
```

Comment: This code could handle multiple strings not starting with numbers?

Comment: @RobertoT yes, as in this example.

Comment: @AllanCameron this is great, thank you! Your solution serves my purposes perfectly and is generalisable to all of my data. Really appreciate it.

Comment: @AllanCameron another question, if I may. If I wanted to apply this to a column of a data frame in which each value is a list, Could that be done? I'm having trouble figuring this out as the specific list is referenced in the strsplit call

Comment: @r0bt the strsplit splits the strings at non-digit characters, leaving only strings of digits (and some empty strings) behind. The result of strsplit is a list of vectors of strings (one vector for each entry in the original vector). This is passed to sapply, where the empty strings are removed, the result is converted from character to numeric, and the minimum integer is selected. These are automatically put into a single numeric vector by `sapply`, and this gives us the object `o` which is used to order the original vector.

Comment: @r0bt your second question is a bit unclear to me. In R, a `list` is not the same as a vector. In your example, the object `mylist` is actually a character vector. To use the above method for a column in a data frame, you would replace `mylist` with the column. For example, if you had a data frame called `df` and a column called `colA` you would replace `mylist` in the above example with `df$colA`

Comment: @AllanCameron Thank you for taking the time to answer. Apologies for my lack of clarity with terminology, I'm still quite new to this. I've added an update to my post to elaborate more and provide a working example that more closely resembles my use that will hopefully clarify what I  mean.