# R Create a data frame summarising per column unique values from another data frame and sort

Tags: r

This question follows on from a discussion began [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72939176/r-order-list-based-on-multiple-characters-from-each-item/72939262?noredirect=1#comment128830081_72939262). I felt that further elaboration added warranted the posting of a new question as it diverges from the question in the original post. Apologies, if I am mistaken in doing so.

Given a data frame similar to the following:

```r
mydf <- data.frame(X1=c("0_times","3-10_times", "11-20_times", "1-2_times","3-10_times",
                        "0_times","3-10_times", "11-20_times", "1-2_times","3-10_times" ),
                   X2=c('ab','bb','cb','db','eb','ab','bb','cb','db','eb'),
                   X3=c("11-20_times", "3-10_times","1-2_times","21-30_times","more_than_30_times",
                        "11-20_times", "3-10_times","1-2_times","21-30_times","more_than_30_times"),
                   X4=c("foo", "bar","fizz","buzz","weee","foo", "bar","fizz","buzz","weee"),
                   X5=c("3-10_times","1-2_times","0_times","more_than_30_times","11-20_times",
                        "21-30_times","1-2_times","0_times","3-10_times","11-20_times")
                   )
```

I would like to create a second data frame to store the column names and a list/vector of unique values from the first dataframe.

Resulting in something like:

```
 names   vals
1    X1 0_times, 1-2_times, 3-10_times, 11-20_times
2    X2 ab, bb, cb, db, eb
3    X3 1-2_times, 3-10_times, 11-20_times , 21-30_times, more_than_30_times 
4    X4 foo, bar, fizz, buzz, weee 
1    X5 0_times,1-2_times,3-10_times,11-20_times,21-30_times
```

I create the second data frame using:

```r
mydf2 <- data.frame(names = colnames(mydf))
mydf2$vals <- lapply(mydf, unique)
```

I think this is okay so far. However, the challenge I have is that I need vectors containing digits (in  this case only `mydf2$X1`) to be sorted in ascending order using more than just the first digit of each item.

With some great help from a [Stack user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72939176/r-order-list-based-on-multiple-characters-from-each-item/72939262?noredirect=1#comment128830081_72939262), this was suggested as a means to sort the vectors containing digits and it works perfectly on a single vector:

```r
mylist <- c('0_times','3-10_times','11_20_times','1-2_times','more_than_20_times')

o <- sapply(strsplit(mylist, '\\D+'), function(x) min(as.numeric(x[nzchar(x)])))
mylist[order(o)]
```

When I attempt to apply this to the entire `mydf2$vals` column by substituting in the column name:

```r
o <- sapply(strsplit(mydf2$vals, '\\D+'), function(x) min(as.numeric(x[nzchar(x)])))
mydf2$vals[order(o)]
```

I receive  the error `error in evaluating the argument 'X' in selecting a method for function 'sapply': non-character argument`

So I have 2 questions:

1. Is there a simpler way of achieving my aims?
2. How can I amend the suggested sort function so the error doesn't occur?

Comment: I feel as if this is a question that arises towars the end of a workflow.  You find yourself in a somewhat awkward situation, but I can't help feeling that much of the awkwardness could be avoided by redesigning earlier stages of the workflow.  Is this, perhaps, an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Comment: @Limey It could well be! I realise I could have gone down a rabbit hole here, hence the reason I also asked if there is just simply another approach to achieve my desired outcome.

Comment: Then perhaps you might take a step back, post your data *at the very start* of the workflow and provide you eexpected output, based on that test data.  Maybe in a different question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could wrap [*@Allan Cameron*'s logic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72939262/6574038) in a function, that extends it to sort the columns' `unique` values. `if` there are numbers included, which `grepl` will tell us, we apply the logic. I called it `makeLevels` because it might be useful to create factor levels as well.

```
makeLevels <- \(x) {
  if (any(grepl('\\d', x))) {
    unique(x[order(sapply(strsplit(x, '\\D+'), function(x) min(as.numeric(x[nzchar(x)]))))])
  } else {
    sort(unique(x))
  }
}

lapply(names(mydf), \(x) data.frame(names=x, vals=toString(makeLevels(mydf[[x]])))) |>
  do.call(what=rbind)
#   names                                                                         vals
# 1    X1                                  0_times, 1-2_times, 3-10_times, 11-20_times
# 2    X2                                                           ab, bb, cb, db, eb
# 3    X3          1-2_times, 3-10_times, 11-20_times, 21-30_times, more_than_30_times
# 4    X4                                                   bar, buzz, fizz, foo, weee
# 5    X5 0_times, 1-2_times, 3-10_times, 11-20_times, 21-30_times, more_than_30_times
```

**Or** do something like this,

```
lapply(names(mydf), \(x) sprintf('$ %s <%s>: %s', x, class(mydf[[x]]), toString(makeLevels(mydf[[x]])))) |>
  do.call(what=rbind)
#      [,1]                                                                                            
# [1,] "$ X1 <character>: 0_times, 1-2_times, 3-10_times, 11-20_times"                                 
# [2,] "$ X2 <character>: ab, bb, cb, db, eb"                                                          
# [3,] "$ X3 <character>: 1-2_times, 3-10_times, 11-20_times, 21-30_times, more_than_30_times"         
# [4,] "$ X4 <character>: bar, buzz, fizz, foo, weee"                                                  
# [5,] "$ X5 <character>: 0_times, 1-2_times, 3-10_times, 11-20_times, 21-30_times, more_than_30_times"
```

which is similar to what `str(mydf)` does; you actually could `lapply` `makeLevels` and `str` it, if you just wanna read it.

```
str(lapply(mydf, makeLevels), vec.len=10L)
# List of 5
#  $ X1: chr [1:4] "0_times" "1-2_times" "3-10_times" "11-20_times"
#  $ X2: chr [1:5] "ab" "bb" "cb" "db" "eb"
#  $ X3: chr [1:5] "1-2_times" "3-10_times" "11-20_times" "21-30_times" "more_than_30_times"
#  $ X4: chr [1:5] "bar" "buzz" "fizz" "foo" "weee"
#  $ X5: chr [1:6] "0_times" "1-2_times" "3-10_times" "11-20_times" "21-30_times" "more_than_30_times"
```

...

Comment: Your first suggestion serves my purposes well. Though, I'll be honest, it's going to take me some time to unpick it so I understand it! Really appreciate your time and help. Thank you!

Comment: @r0bt Thanks for feedback. I added some explanation that might help.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps just reset the order of `mydf` (i.e. pasting a leading 0 to the `X1` column):

```
mydf <- mydf[order(ifelse(substr(mydf$X1,1,2)!=11, paste0("0",mydf$X1), mydf$X1)),]
```

Then run the same code above for `mydf2`, and you will get this:

```
  names                                        vals
1    X1 0_times, 1-2_times, 3-10_times, 11-20_times
2    X2                          ab, db, bb, eb, cb
```

Is that the expected output?

Comment: Thank you, it does for this example! In my actual use case, I have multiple columns similar to X1 from which sorted lists of the unique values are required. I'm assuming my implementation would need to iterate over each of those columns meaning that a loop or apply function is required?

Comment: Perhaps show an example with multiple columns like X1, and the expected output

Comment: I've edited the post for further illustration :-)